# returning either a rvalue or an lvalue

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

I want to define `s[i]` to return `0` if `s[0]` was never assigned and return a reference to `s[i]` if `s[i]` was assigned earlier (to implement a sparse array).  The following code does it, but it ends up creating `s[i]` whenever I try to get its value, because of the semantics of map.

```
struct svec{
  map<int,double> vals;
  /*                                                                                                
  double operator[](int index){                                                                     
    return (vals.count(index) > 0) ? vals[index] : 0                                                        ;                                                                           
    else return 0;                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                 
  */
  double &operator[](int index){
    return vals[index];
  }
};

int main(){
svec s;
s[0] = 10;
cout << s[1] << endl;
}
```

I want the commented code to be used for resolving the expression `s[1]`.  But if I uncomment it, I get an error.

Comment: Regarding your outcommented code, the number of entries in a map is *not* equal to some max index. Remember that your map could have values for e.g. the key `0` and `9`. That would make the size of the map equal to `2`, but the max "index" is `9`. You also should make the overload returning by value `const`, as in `double operator[](int index) const;`. Lastly, if you can only have non-negative (i.e. positive numbers and zero) then use `unsigned` instead of `int`.

Comment: As for your problem, you need to think about what it means to give an invalid "index". Should it return a default value? Should it throw an exception? Should you even have a map as the underlying data type? Why not a vector (which seems to fit a little better for this)?

Comment: I would like the default value 0 to be returned.

Comment: A function can only have one return type. You can't return both an lvalue and an rvalue

Comment: You can't have a function return a different type depending on its argument values. Rethink your design.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload return values, so you'll have to stick with either returning by reference or by value (or by pointer, etc). The problem with returning by reference is that you have to refer to an existing value that lives in memory. This is, of course, fine when the value is in the map. When it's not, you have to create the default value and store it in memory. Then you have to make sure to properly delete it to not leak memory, but also to make sure the user isn't holding references to the values, as it would introduce unexpected behaviour.

Also, you have to consider the fact that the user can change the value you're returning. If you return the same default, then it's possible for the user to change it to another value. Then all subsequent calls would return a reference to the new value. Resetting the default to 0 every time you return it would also be unexpected for all users that are still keeping a reference to it.

You probably could solve this problem in a stable way, but it would probably require much boilerplate code. I would suggest putting the burden on the user in this case.

```
class SparseVector {
private:
    std::unordered_map<int, double> elements;

public:
    void set(int index, double value) {
        elements[index] = value;
    }

    double& get(int index, double& optional) {
        auto it = elements.find(index);
        if (it != elements.end())
            return it->second;
        else
            return optional;
    }

    double& get(int index) {
        auto it = elements.find(index);
        if (it != elements.end())
            return it->second;
        throw std::runtime_error(
            "Couldn't find element at index " + std::to_string(index) + 
            "! Use get(int index, double& optional) if you don't want errors."
        );
    }
}

int main() {
    double default_value = 0.0;
    SparseVector vector;

    std::cout << vector.get(0, default_value) << std::endl;
}
```